# Using conditions within a try catch block

Tags: javascript

```
const mutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({

    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addArticle: {
            type: articleDataNode,
            args: {
                    title: {type: GraphQLString},
                    content: {type: GraphQLString},
                    author_id: {type: GraphQLID}

                },
                resolve(parent, args){

                    try{

                        console.log(args.content);
                        if((args.title && args.content && args.author_id) !==  undefined){
                            let articleModel = new articleModel_i({
                                title: args.title,
                                content: args.content,
                                author_id: args.author_id, //Author ID should come from somewhere in applciation
                                createdAt: String(new Date())
                            })
                            return articleModel.save();
                            }else throw new Error("Arguments are not defined!")


                    }catch(e){ throw e}

                    }
        },
        addUser:{
            type: userDataNode,
            args: {
                username: {type: GraphQLString},
                firstname: {type: GraphQLString},
                lastname: {type: GraphQLString}
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                let newUser = new userModel_i({
                    username: args.username, firstname: args.firstname, lastname: args.lastname, createdAt: String(new Date())
                });
                return newUser.save();
            }
        }


    }
})
```

Im building an application which performs CRUD on articles. When a user creates an article, they are required to pass in some parameters. If the parameters don't exist, then the program should throw an error. In the above example, have i used a try and catch block correctly? Will this terminate my program if an error occurs? Or will it pass control after catching the error?

Comment: `catch(e){ throw e; }` is pretty meaningless - you could just omit the whole `try` wrapper and it would throw the exact same exception

Comment: changed it to console.log, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand what happens when an error is thrown and what javascript runs or not, I wrote this. Just run it your console.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        throw "err";
        console.log("not happening");
    });
}
setTimeout(() => console.log("DONE"), 1000);
```

What happens is that the excution you were in dies and no code after that will be executed and thus also no calls etc. But other functions getting executed later, independant of the crashing function will.

Also please dont rethrow the same exception in the catch { }. It is the same as not catching it but hides valuable debug information that was available in the first error on why it happened.